# input field value is not resetting correctly

Tags: javascript, dom

```
save.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  hiddenfield.value = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < listy.length; i++) {
    queue.push(listy[i].textContent.slice(0, -1));
    console.log(queue);
  }
  obj["user-data"] = queue;

  objstring = JSON.stringify(obj);
  dataObjectBase64 = btoa(objstring);
  hiddenfield.value = dataObjectBase64;
});
```

I have a hidden input field which populates with the some data on clicking save button but instead of replacing the data ,the value gets appended to the previous data, i have tried resetting the value at the beginning of callback function but its not working, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: There are too many unknowns in your code. What is `queue`? What is `listy`? What is `obj`? This is why we always recommend people to share a minimal, concrete and verifiable example.

Comment: that is out of context right, still, queue is a container to store the page data and listy is a container containing the html  elements .,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set `queue` to an empty array at the beginning of the function.